# How to include a horizontal line in the header?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor-pdf

I have the following, custom theme defined:

```
extends:
  - default-with-fallback-font
footer:
  recto:
    right:
      content: '{chapter-title} | *{page-number}*'
  verso:
    left:
      content: '*{page-number}* | {chapter-title}'
header:
  height: $base_line_height_length * 4
  recto:
    center:
      content: '{document-title}'
  verso:
    center:
      content: '{document-title}'
```

Now I would like to separate the header visually a little more by introducing a horizontal line.
In "normal" asciidoc text, I can do a horizontal line/ rule by using `'''`

When I try to apply this to the header, the header will not be rendered anymore.

```
header:
  height: $base_line_height_length * 4
  recto:
    center:
      content: '{document-title}' '''
  verso:
    center:
      content: '{document-title}' '''
```

How can I add a horizontal line/ rule to the header section of my asciidoc?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a header border? This creates a horizontal line directly under you header. You can do this in the styling like this:

```
extends: default
header:
  height: 0.75in
  border-color: #DDDDDD
  border-width: 0.25
```